# how can i filter comments by user and by article with get_context_data Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i want to filter the comments by user and by post. would you like to tell me how can i filter the comment using `get_context_data`. i am getting this error with that code `'NewsDetailView' object has no attribute 'get_object_or_404'` how can i solve this issue?

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article.title
```

views.py

```
class NewsDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'news/news_detail.html'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        self.object = self.get_object_or_404(Article, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = self.object
        context['form'] = CommentForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            form.instance.article = Article.objects.get(
                pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            form.instance.commentator = self.request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('news:news-detail', pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        else:
            return redirect('news:news-detail', pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NewsDetailView` indeed has no `get_object_or_404`, so using `self.get_object_or_404` does not make any sense. Furthermore it is not necessary at all.

You can obtain the `Comment`s that belong to a user with the *`username`* with `self.object.comment_set.filter(commentator__username=username)`

You can further use the [**`FormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) to avoid some boilerplate code to construct the form and redirect to the success url:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class NewsDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'news/news_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = self.object.comment_set.filter(
            commentator__username=self.kwargs['username']
        )
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.article_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.commentator = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('news:news-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Comment: now m getting this error `commentator__username=self.kwargs['username']) KeyError: 'username'`?

Comment: @afi: that means that your `url` has no `username` parameter. If you want to use the *logged in* user, you should use `request.user`, not `self.kwargs['username']`.

Comment: now m adding this like `self.request.user` it's working detail page is load but i m try to make a comment now i am getting error `TypeError: 'QueryDict' object is not callable` what should i do

Comment: @afi: yes, it is `form = self.get_form()`. Made a typo while editing.

Comment: what to do now ? this error `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` is showing.

Comment: this error is highlighted there `form.instance.article_id = self.kwargs.get['pk']` ?

Comment: @afi: it is `self.kwargs['pk']`. Please do not write `self.kwargs.get` in your views. Except for some specific circumstances, it is really a problematic pattern. As is written in the *Zen of Python*: exceptions should not pass silently.